# Using LINQ with NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Ok, I think I have all my configurations right and now I am just trying to do a select query from the database selecting some data.  Now I am using NHibernate 3.0 which I though by default support LINQ (or at least a good portion of link.  Now every LINQ example I find has this code

```
session.Linq<User>()
```

but I for the life of me can't find how or where session is being set.  Is this that proper why of doing in in 3.0 and if so how do I set sessions (what usings do I need, classes, methods, etc...)?  If not, what is the proper way of using LINQ with NHibernate 3.0?

UPDATE:

Now I have the following code:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.Configure();
configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Tag).Assembly);
var sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
var session = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```

but I get a compiler error saying that NHibernate.ISession does not have a definition for Linq.  I have the follow usings:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyProject.Models;
using MyProject.ViewModels.Desktop;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it's `session.Query<User>()` in NHibernate 3 as the LINQ provider was brought into the core assembly

Comment: The NHibernate wiki is a good resource for getting started - http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the namespace:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

Also, it's now:

```
session.Query<TEntity>();
```

instead of:

```
// Deprecated
session.Linq<TEntity>();
```

Comment: Yes, I did figure out that I needed to use .Query instead of .Linq for NHibernate 3, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You get a session from the NHibernate `SessionFactory.CreateSession()` method.  Once you have one, you can then use either HQL queries, the NH query API or LINQ to access the data.